# JQuery - IF statement only works two to three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make this page working that has a vertical line of pictures (thumbnail-sized) which you can then click on to make them scroll to full width and show lots of text and happy stuff.
I've already managed to do all that. However, if I click on one thumbnail, any open thumbnails are supposed to close. I've implemented an IF statement and class-checking for that:

```
$("a#shins-rec1").clickToggle(
function(){
        if ($(".shins-rec").hasClass('done')) {
            $(".shins-rec").filter($(".done").not($(this))).animate({
              left: $(".shins-rec").filter($(".done").not($(this))).width() / 2 - 60,
              width: '120px'}, 250, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('done');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().animate({left: 0, width:'100%'}, 250, function(){
                $(this).addClass('done')
            });
        };
},
function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({
      left: $(this).parent().width() / 2 - 60,
      width: '120px'}, 250, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('done')
    }); // even clicks
});
```

which works all fine, but after you clicked two or three times on different thumbnails to open them and close the other ones, the already open thumbnail gets stuck and the clicked thumbnail opens as it should open. You have to click on the clicked thumbnail to close the other one, and then you have to wait some time till you can click the clicked thumbnail to properly close it again. After that it just stays like this.

I've already tried doing it with a plugin called Summer of GOTO, because I think it has something to do with checking whether there are any "done" classes or not, so I wanted to make it re-check stuff using goto in JQuery. Using a WHILE statement didn't work either, but that could be because I don't understand that function.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** : [JSfiddle of what I'm working on](http://jsfiddle.net/AwGEH/117/)

Comment: Is it possible to show a replica of the above with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: or at least provide the console output when the image gets stuck...

Comment: try adding `.stop()` before the `.animate` sounds as if the click is happening before the previous click finishes which is then setting the wrong class on animation  finished

Comment: @chridam Ah, yes, I forgot. I edited in the question just now :).

Comment: @Pete You mean like [...] filter($(".done").not($(this))).stop().animate({left: [...] ? That doesn't do anything different, but I guess it still would be good to put it in the code, in case people click to fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally gotten the answer to my problem, someone on another forum kind of rewrote my code because it was messy and things were repetitive and they solved the stuckness.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AwGEH/143/) is the JSfiddle in case anyone wants to look into it.

For some reason the orientation of the thumbnails changed which made a 0 value for "left" position the thumbnail in the center and a 240 or similar made it shift to the right. But I simply changed that by switching the left-values and changing the 240 or similar into a negative number, as seen below.

```
var rightPos = -1 * ($('div.content-ins-used').width() / 2 - 60);
```

Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the click even which you fire on each thumbnail has same ID, ID of the element suppose to be unique, you can use class instead like this

```
$("a.shins-rec1").clickToggle(
function(){
        if ($(".shins-rec").hasClass('done')) {
            $(".shins-rec").filter($(".done").not($(this))).animate({
              left: $(".shins-rec").filter($(".done").not($(this))).width() / 2 - 60,
              width: '120px'}, 250, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('done');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().animate({left: 0, width:'100%'}, 250, function(){
                $(this).addClass('done')
            });
        };
},
function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({
      left: $(this).parent().width() / 2 - 60,
      width: '120px'}, 250, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('done')
    }); // even clicks
});
```

Comment: They have different ID's, but I forgot to add my JSfiddle to the question, so it couldn't be seen. The question contains the sample now, though.